# Abort a PHP script trying to connect through SSH with an Ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ssh

Bonjour, 
I'm a trying to connect to a router with PHP and [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/phpseclib).

```
<?php
    function connect_ssh(){

    set_time_limit(10);
    ob_start();

    register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

    if(connection_aborded()){
       die();
    }


    function shutdown(){
       print ob_get_clean();
    }

       $res = array();
       $a = new Net_SSH2($host);

       $a->write("show time\r\n");


     try{
        $res[] = $a->read('\r\n');
        $res[] = $a->read('\r\n');
        $res[] = $a->read('#');

     } catch(Exception $e)
     {    

          ob_flush();
          var_dump(compact('e','res'));
     }


    } return json_encode(compact('e','res'));?>
```

Im calling this function using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
 url:'myURL',
 data: null,
 type: 'POST',
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(z){ console.log(z);}
});
```

**I would like to stop my php script on demande because sometimes, the "Net_SSH2::read()" failed if the parameter is not found in the routeur answer. (i.e if there is a syntaxe error).**

*The more often, I am not able to reconnect to my web server after a failed request and I have to wait for a long time or even reboot Apache...*

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Make it check a database in a loop and post the AJAX bit to another script that just inserts a quit value into the database.

EDIT:
I'm not sure if I completely understand your code, but here's what I would do:

```
function() {
    $con = database_of_choice($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    while (!$quitter) {
        $r = $con->query('SELECT shouldquit FROM info LIMIT 1');
        if ($r['shouldquit'] == 'quit') {
            $quitter = true;
            continue;
        }
        //important connection stuff here...      
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hum, Im not sure I understand... My problem is that my PHP script never ends if the $a->read() function failed... The SSH session still exists after pressing ESCAPE on my keyboard, and I have to restart Apache to be able to retry...

Comment: check the edit, i didn't test, so there could be mistakes. but it shows what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

you can set lower `max_execution_time` in runtime:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 10); // maximal execution time in seconds
```

This ensures that the script itself ends after 10 seconds, even if it has not been completed. Time you have to choose, depending on how long it can take up.